# How to save a PHP string with variable not explicit?

Tags: php, string, variables, date, internationalization

I have an array like this:

```
$list = array (
  "Today is ".$aaaa."/".$mm."/".$gg,
  "Oggi è il ".$gg."/".$mm."/".$aaaa,
  "Aujourd'hui, c'est ".$gg."/".$mm."/".$aaaa
);
```

I would like to save them in a database (with variables not explicit) and then re-use them in php format.
Is it possible to save as string a string in php format?

Example:

```
$gg = 1;
$myString = "Today is ".$gg;
echo $myString;

$gg = 17;
echo $myString;
```

This example, of course, show always "Today is 1".
I would like it show "Today is 1", "Today is 17".
Can I save myString with variables not explicit?

Comment: try [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: It looks like you're looking for internationalization. Keep datetime objects and a format specifier for the country you want to support. The `$gg`, `$mm` and `$aaaa` will mostly only stand in your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
$myString = "Today is %s";

$today = '21/12/2012';
printf($myString,$today); // Today is 21/12/2012

$today = 21;
printf($myString,$today); // Today is 21
```

`printf` will output directly the string.
`sprintf` will return it

EDIT: in your specific case you should specific the order

```
$list = array (
  'Today is %1$s/%2$s/%3$s',
  'Oggi è il %3$s/%2$s/%1$s',
  'Aujourd\'hui, c\'est %3$s/%2$s/%1$s'
);

foreach($list as $string) {
    printf($string,"2012","12","21");
    echo  " <br />";
}
```

However for localization I would use the [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function for simple strings and [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) (with setlocale) for localized dates

Comment: How to do with a for cycle if variables order is different? (see array in the question)

Answer (score 3):

use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php) and save the format.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I save myString with variables not explicit?

Sort of, yes. You can implement that:

```
class MyStringVariable
{
    private $mask;
    private $variables;

    public function __construct($mask, array $variables) {
        $this->mask = $mask;
        $this->variables = $variables;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return vsprintf($this->mask, $this->variables);
    }
}
```

Usage ([Demo](http://eval.in/5101)):

```
$gg = 1;
$myString = new MyStringVariable("Today is %s\n", [&$gg]);
echo $myString;

$gg = 17;
echo $myString;
```

Output:

```
Today is 1
Today is 17
```

This works basically by wrapping `vsprintf` (see [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf)) into an object of it's own that also stores the variable references you want to make use of. The [magic `__toString` method](http://php.net/language.oop5.magic) takes care of resolving the output when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'My var is %s';

$a = 100;
$foo = sprintf($sql, $a);
```

**EDIT 1;**

```
$list = array(
    "Today is %s/%s/%s",
    "Oggi è il %s/%s/%s",
    "Aujourd'hui, c'est %s/%s/%s"
);

foreach ($list as $str)
{
    $a   = 2012;
    $m   = 12;
    $g   = 17;

    if (strstr($str, 'Today '))
        $foo = sprintf($str, $a, $m, $g);
    else
        $foo = sprintf($str, $g, $m, $a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if this is the best way but it works,
you save the lines as strings, and with eval() then convert to variables

```
$list = array (
    'Today is ".$aaaa."/".$mm."/".$gg'
);
$aaaa = 2012;
$mm = 11;
$gg = 00;
eval("\$mylist = \"$list[0];");
echo $mylist;
```

Happy coding !!